# How does `hector_mapping` build the coordinate system?

Tags: slam, localization, navigation, ros-kinetic, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I want to know the localization accuracy of [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping), so I need to measure the actual position of the robot and compare it with the position of `hector_mapping` publish on `slam_out_pose`. As far as I know, after the [cartographer](https://github.com/googlecartographer/cartographer) starts, the direction in which the robot advances is defined as the positive direction of the x-axis, and then based on this coordinate system, the position information of the robot is output. Is `hector_mapping` based on such a mechanism to establish a coordinate system? If not, what is the `hector_mapping based on to establish the coordinate system?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320660/how-does-%60hector_mapping%60-build-the-coordinate-system?/) by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2019-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, hector_mapping uses the standard ROS coordinate frame convention (see [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html)). It starts mapping at the zero pose (translations zero and identity quaternion) with x pointing forwards, y left, z up and estimates the robot pose relative to that.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2019-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-04-09**:
Thank you,sir! After solving this problem, I have a new [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/320728/get-the-localization-track-of-hector_mapping/): How to test the accuracy of `hector_mapping`'s localization?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2019-05-06**:
This depends on the application. A common way of testing a SLAM algorithms accuracy is testing loop closure performance.